# How to visualize the component hierarchy of an Angular.js application?

Tags: angularjs

I am working on an incremental React migration and I am starting at the bottom of the component tree of a large Angular.js product that maintains many directives and components.

Is there a tool that given an entry point will build a tree of all possible DOM elements created by the service ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the extensions from the chrome. 
I recommend [Angular Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon)